# Multi-Level Includes in CodeFirst - EntityFrameWork

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

It is working code;

```
IQueryable<Product> productQuery = ctx.Set<Product>().Where(p => p.Id == id).(Include"Contexts.AdditionalProperties.Field");
```

But you know that it could not produce compile time error if we made mistake in string statement in "Contexts.AdditionalProperties.Field"

I would like to write code below;

```
IQueryable<Product> productQuery = ctx.Set<Product>().Where(p => p.Id == id).Include(p => p.Contexts);
```

But above statement could not give chance to define AdditionalProperties and Field.

What should we do?

I would like to write as  more than one include for build query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If *AdditionalProperties* is a single reference to another object:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
...
IQueryable<Product> productQuery = ctx.Set<Product>()
        .Include(p => p.Contexts.AdditionalProperties.Field)
        .Where(p => p.Id == id);
```

If *AdditionalProperties* is a collection then you can use the *Select* method:

```
IQueryable<Product> productQuery = ctx.Set<Product>()
        .Include(p => p.Contexts.AdditionalProperties.Select(a => a.Field))
        .Where(p => p.Id == id);
```

Don't forget to import *System.Data.Entity* namespace in your class file!

Comment: I have to tell you that it was *not* a fair game... Since I answered this very question a few months ago here. Sorry dude!

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! How can I add another where contion for AdditionalProperties which is a List<> type object?

Comment: You can't. Include does not let conditional loading on the navigation properties. For that you need to eliminate the Include and load the filtered navigation properties by a *Filtered Projection* with Anonymous types. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718400/conditional-eager-loading/3718457#3718457