# EF CTP5 - Strongly-Typed Eager Loading - How to Include Nested Navigational Properties?

Tags: entity-framework, poco, eager-loading, entity-framework-ctp5

Attempting to cutover our EF4 solution to EF CTP5, and ran into a problem.

Here's the relevant portion of the model:

[image]

The pertinent relationship:
 - A single **County** has **many Cities**
 - A single **City** has a **single State**

Now, i want to perform the following query:
 - Get all Counties in the system, and include all the Cities, and all the State's for those Cities.

In EF4, i would do this:

```
var query = ctx.Counties.Include("Cities.State");
```

In EF CTP5, we have a strongly typed Include, which takes an `Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>>`.

I can get all the Cities for the County no problem:

```
var query = ctx.Counties.Include(x => x.Cities);
```

But how can i get the *State* for those Cities too?

I am using pure POCO's, so `County.Cities` is an `ICollection<City>`, therefore i cannot do this:

```
var query = ctx.Counties.Include(x => x.Cities.State)
```

As `ICollection<City>` does not have a property called `State`.

It's almost like i need to use a nested IQueryable.

Any ideas? Do i need to fallback to the magic string Include in this scenario?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For that you can use you the *Select* method:

```
var query = ctx.Counties.Include(x => x.Cities.Select(c => c.State))
```

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750900/multi-level-includes-in-codefirst-entityframework/4751376#4751376) you can find another example.

Comment: clever! trying now...stay tuned.

Comment: Works great, thanks a bunch man! +1 and accepted. Haven't seen you answering many EF4 questions lately - Ladislav is taking us both down. :)

Comment: No problem buddy! That's because I'm totally focused on EF Code First questions. I hope you start using it as well, since I still see EDMX file on your question :)

Comment: Yeah, what can i say - i like having the pretty diagram. :)

Comment: need your help (if you can). :) See my (related) question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189268/problem-with-eager-loading-nested-navigation-based-on-abstract-entity-ef-ctp5