# Problem with include property based on Abstract Entity (EF 4.1)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, eager-loading, entity-framework-4.1

the LoadProperty is good alternative for Include method... [Problem with Eager Loading Nested Navigation Based on Abstract Entity (EF CTP5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189268/problem-with-eager-loading-nested-navigation-based-on-abstract-entity-ef-ctp5)

But I can't do it in my Repository because i haven't context, I just have IDbSet. Think you it's bad idea ? Should I have the DbContext instead of IDbSet ? Or an other alternative is possible ? (My problem is similar to the referenced link) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DbContext` in repository. You can need it for much more operations and because repository is already dependent on EF there is no reason to hide context from it.

Comment: Ok, in case of I want to get all Entity with associations (the scenario in referenced link is to find one entity and load its property), how can I do-it ?

Comment: If you want all entities with associations you usually call `context.Entities.Include(...)` You must be more specific.

Comment: But if you want to mock repository for test how you made for context ?

Comment: @rad: Why do you need context if you mock whole repository?

Comment: sorry, i wasn't very clear. If I want unit testing my repository I do mock Context