# Can you include more than just one relationship level using lambdas in linq to entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a data structure in which Users have UserPlans and UserPlans have Plans.  I've included a using statement for System.Data.Entity so that I can strongly type my includes, but I can't figure out if there's a way to strongly type an include that goes more than one level deep in the relationships.  So I have:

```
from user in entities.Users.Include(u => u.UserPlans).Include("UserPlans.Plans")
```

but I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
from user in entities.Users.Include(u => u.UserPlans).Include(u => u.UserPlans.Include(up => up.Plan))
```

In order not to have the string in my include.  Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this has been answered before: [EF CTP5 - Strongly-Typed Eager Loading - How to Include Nested Navigational Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811557/ef-ctp5-strongly-typed-eager-loading-how-to-include-nested-navigational-prop)

Basically:

```
from user in entities.Users.Include(u => u.UserPlans.Select(p => p.Plans))
```